# How to remove default tooltip from menu item in collapsable state with sidebar?

Tags: antd

How to remove default tooltip from a menu item in a collapsible state with sidebar? It seems like the same question asked in the ant design GitHub also, but no response. Code and screenshot below.

```
<Menu.Item key="profile">
          <Link to={`${baseConfig.page.profile.url}`}>
            <span className="isoMenuHolder" style={{color:'#ffffff'}}>
              <i className="icon-admin" />
              <span className="nav-text">
                &nbsp;Settings
              </span>
            </span>
          </Link>
        </Menu.Item>
```

[image]

Comment: What I understood from my research, its default behavior of the collapsable view of sidebar menu. At present, there is no option to disable it. So I have used the expand the view and override the style using CSS.

Comment: can you reply with your css code which you used to override default antd css...Thanks

Comment: The tooltip is applicable for collapsable mode only, I have decided to use expanded mode always, then I have adjusted the width and menu item style with an expanded mode.

Answer (score 1):

Take it out with css

```
    .ant-tooltip {
      display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

since the new changes on antd (> 4.23.3), the `<Menu.Item />` component was deprecated, with the new API they provide a way to make the tooltip disappear by defining the `title` attribute as `null` or as an empty string on the items list like:

```
const items = [
   {
     key: "0",
     title: "", //this makes the tooltip disappear
     label: "Any Label"
   }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my workaround helps you or not but I have a collapse/expand button within the `Menu` and it displays the color of the button as the tooltip. So i removed the `Menu.Item` and the tooltip disappeared

```
          <Menu
            mode="inline"
            theme="light"
            inlineCollapsed={this.state.menuCollapsed}
            className="CollapseButtonMenu"
          >
            <Button type="primary" onClick={this.toggleCollapsed} style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
                <Icon type={this.state.menuCollapsed ? 'menu-unfold' : 'menu-fold'} />
            </Button>
          </Menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but I want to use the Menu.Item in my scenario.